# Firebase - Access a full path Url

Tags: firebase, routes

I successflly deployed a web application on firebase.

When i access it from the url everything is okay and i can navigate to `myapp.web.app/Help`.

But when i tried a direct access to the url `.web.app/Help` : [image: page not found]

When running on local, the `localhost:8100/Help` is working. How to do the same on Firebase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your firebase.json:

```
// firebase.json

{
  "hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[Source](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#firebase)